How to fix Rollup.Js "Unresolved Dependency" for package that is in a yarn workspace
I have a yarn workspace with 2 packages in it. One is a react ts component library, and one is a types package. The component library uses the types library. When I build my component library using Rollup, I get this warning:
(!) Unresolved dependencies
https://rollupjs.org/troubleshooting/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
@oneface-react/types (imported by "src/components/ComponentA/ComponentA.tsx")

I am wondering how to fix this since this unresolved dependency is my other package in my workspace and it wont be in the node_modules of the component library.
Here is my rollup config:
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import image from "@rollup/plugin-image";
import pkg from "./package.json";

export default {
  input: "src/index.ts",
  output: [
    {
      file: "./dist/cjs/index.js",
      format: "cjs",
    },
    {
      file: "./dist/esm/index.js",
      format: "esm",
    },
  ],
  onwarn: function (warning, handler) {
    // Skip certain warnings

    // should intercept ... but doesn't in some rollup versions
    if (warning.code === "THIS_IS_UNDEFINED") {
      return;
    }

    // console.warn everything else
    handler(warning);
  },
  external: [...Object.keys(pkg.peerDependencies || {})],
  plugins: [
    resolve({
      preserveSymlinks: true,
    }),
    peerDepsExternal(),
    commonjs(),
    terser(),
    image(),
    typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json", clean: true }),
  ],
};

and my package.json for my component library:
  "name": "@oneface-react/components",
  "version": "0.0.4",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "./dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "./dist/esm/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/esm/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "/dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "yarn lint && yarn clean && rollup -c --bundleConfigAsCjs",
    "dev": "rollup -c --bundleConfigAsCjs -w",
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}\"",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "clean:node_modules": "rimraf node_modules",
    "docs": "jsdoc -c jsdoc.conf.json"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^25.0.7",
    "@rollup/plugin-image": "^3.0.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.2.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-replace": "^5.0.5",
    "@rollup/plugin-terser": "^0.4.4",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^11.1.6",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.48",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.22",
    "@types/react-transition-group": "^4.4.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.4.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.33",
    "prettier": "^3.2.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-svg": "^16.1.33",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.5",
    "rollup": "^4.9.6",
    "rollup-plugin-dts": "^6.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.36.0",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "singleQuote": false,
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "tabWidth": 2,
    "semi": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@oneface-react/types": "^1.0.0"
  }
}

my tsconfig for component library:
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "esnext",
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "preserveSymlinks": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@oneface-react/types": ["./types/index.ts"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/components/**/*"],
  "exclude": [
    "dist",
    "node_modules",
    "src/**/*.test.tsx",
    "src/**/*.stories.tsx",
    "docs"
  ]
}

This is my folder structure:
lerna.json
package.json
packages
  types
  components

I tried setting preserveSymlinks: true in my tsconfig as well as rollup config. I also tried to set the path to my types library but that didnt work. Not really sure how to do this.

https://rollupjs.org/troubleshooting/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency this says that external deps won't be bundled and must exist at runtime through some other means. It also suggests plugin-node-resolve is usually the answer. Yarn monorepo adds another layer of questions; usually you'd need your root package.json to declare the packages dir as your workspaces to locally resolve then add via yarn workspace (your-components-package) add Y(your-local-types-package) vs a paths file map in tsconfig. Hope that gives some hints. Don't know lerna or rollup well enough to be confident.

So I have the root package.json with the packages dir with my workspaces in it. I have my 2 workspaces in the packages dir. I have linked them successfully. I just dont know what im supposed to configure in the tsconfig. I am using plugin-node-resolve but that didnt help.
